# Remote variable

Tags: powershell, jobs, scriptblock

I am having an issue with passing variables to a remote powershell session and I've searched everywhere on the internet I can think of so I'm hoping someone out there can help.
I have a function calling a job which is telling it to start a scriptblock

What I'm trying to do is write a script to allow me to failover clusters from one VM.  It works fine if everything is hardcoded but that means I have to change the script for every failover and that just won't save me anytime at all.

```
$Computer = Server1
$Clustergrp = Cluster1


function FAILOVER(){
$job = Start-Job -scriptblock $JobScript
do {[System.Windows.Form.Application]::DoEvent() } until ($Job.State -eq "Completed")


$JobScript = 
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:Computer -ScriptBlock {Move-ClusterGroup -Name $using:Clustergrp}
}
```

What am I missing here?  Help please!

I've tried using arguments and $using:variable but nothing seems to work.  Yet if I hardcode everything in the scriptblock it works everytime.

I've also tried just using `-ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock{.....}` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***General* points:**

- [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command) has an `-AsJob` parameter, so there's no need for creating a job with `Start-Job` first.
- To wait for a job's completion, use the [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Wait-Job) cmdlet.
- If you want to wait *right away*, i.e. if you want *synchronous* execution to begin with, simply omit `-AsJob`.

  - Note that `Invoke-Command`'s `-ComputerName` parameter accepts an *array* of computer names that are then targeted *in parallel*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

You're *nesting* two out-of-runspace (out-of-process) scopes, which also requires nesting the use of the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-remote-variables):

```bash
$Computer = 'Server1'
$Clustergrp = 'Cluster1'

$JobScript = {
  # Create a *local* variable from the caller's
  # $Clustergrp value, so it can again be referenced with
  # $using: in the remotely executing Invoke-Command script block.
  $Clustergrp = $using:Clustergrp
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:Computer -ScriptBlock { 
    Move-ClusterGroup -Name $using:Clustergrp
  }
}

function FAILOVER {
  $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $JobScript
  $job | Wait-Job
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer / solution.  I thought it had to do with a scoping issue but I was too deep in the weeds to see it!  Thank you Mklement0

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Todd; my pleasure. (It _is_ a scoping issue of sorts: the `Invoke-Command` script block sees only the job script block's own variables via `$using:`)

Comment: I will definitely remember this for next time!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:Computer -ArgumentList $arg1 -ScriptBlock {param($arg) Move-ClusterGroup -Name $arg[0]}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  Was $arg1 supposed to be $arg[1], I tried that too and that didn't work.

Comment: also tried `-ArgumentList $args[1] -ScriptBlock {param($arg) Move-ClusterGroup -Name $args[0]}`

Comment: Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ArgumentList $arg1 -ScriptBlock {param($arg) Move-ClusterGroup -Name $arg[0]}

Comment: Dom, nope that didn't work either.  I have a bunch of write-hosts in the function that show that $Clustergrp and $Computer have values.

Comment: I can upload the entire code if that will help.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to select from a drop down list, a cluster node and have powershell fail that cluster over to the other server while displaying a progress bar so it doesn't look like its stuck and then let me know the status of said failover.  Was it successful or did it fail.  I have the code working from the command line for a single cluster so I know the failover cluster part works.  And I would of edited my answer as requested but there were too many edits at the time and I wanted to get my explanation out here.